# ¿Donde está la pestaña destacadas o de recompensas?

Tags: soporte, recompensas, barra-de-navegación

En los demás sitios de Stack Exchange hay un botón que permite ofrecer una recompensa de reputación a cambio de mejores respuestas. Esta pestaña no se ve en la página principal.

[image: inicio]

Pero si hacemos una pregunta la opción de recompensa aparece y si damos click en ella

[image: enlace]

La pestaña aparece

[image: destacadas]

Como el sitio está recién estrena,do es lógico que no haya preguntas con recompensa, pero ¿Es esto normal o es algún bug?

Comment: yo creo que entiendo lo que quieres decir, sobre tu primera imagen solo veras eso en tus pregunta para indicarte de cuando esta sera apta para ello, pero si te fijas y buscas una pregunta que tenga esa opcion habilitada al pasar el tiempo estipulado puedes ver algo como lo siguiente -> iniciar una recompensa, justo debajo de -> agrega un comentario. Y sobre la pestaña me imagino que sera porque no hay ninguna activa en este momento pero se que tiempo atras habian algunas por eso creo que, funcionar funciona, pero esta no es habilitada por lo mencionado Saludos

Comment: el formato que tu muestras me imagino que sera el que ves en tu propia pregunta para indicarte el tiempo, el formato que ves en las mas preguntas creo que es el que te indique anteriormente, tambien te digo que la mayor parte de lo que te digo son conjeturas Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Tus conjeturas están en lo cierto, ese es el formato que sale en tu propia pregunta cuando todavía no ha transcurrido el tiempo necesario para ofrecer recompensa. Como Carlos Muñoz explica no se trata de un bug. Me llamó la atención la ausencia porque yo estoy usando la navegación experimental en el sitio en inglés y la parte de las recompensas llama mucho la atención.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En realidad hasta el momento ya han habido 2 recompensas:

- [two-way bind con Select2 en aurelia.io](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302/two-way-bind-con-select2-en-aurelia-io)
- [Provisionar máquina de Vagrant con Puppet usando el módulo de mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190/provisionar-m%C3%A1quina-de-vagrant-con-puppet-usando-el-m%C3%B3dulo-de-mysql)

Actualmente no hay ninguna recompensa activa por lo que esa pestaña aparece vacía. Esto es el comportamiento esperado, no es ningún bug.

Answer (score 2):

### [Anúncio dinámico de Recompensas Activas creado por Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1873/21950)

La imagen abajo se **actualiza en tiempo real** conforme las recompensas activas en el site principal; es un app en Heroku y funciona conforme el site Stack Exchange donde es insertada.

[image]

<sub>PS: ejemplo de [la misma imagen en meta.pt.so](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2162/201)</sub>

Comment: Parece ser que el texto de este enlace http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/bounty.png está roto, sin embargo, redirecciona a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured

Comment: Se ve que Community cambió el enlace porque ahora https es exigido, pero ya no funciona el banner...

Comment: @Flxtr solucionado